# Caffe2 Import Throwing Error in Python free() invalid size

Tags: caffe2

I'm trying to import the following modules for a Caffe2 tutorial.

Tutorial here: https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/blob/master/caffe2/python/tutorials/Loading_Pretrained_Models.ipynb

Modules here: 
%matplotlib inline
from caffe2.proto import caffe2_pb2
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
import skimage.transform
from matplotlib import pyplot
import os
from caffe2.python import core, workspace, models
import urllib2
print("Required modules imported.")

But it's throwing the following at import. 
"*** Error in `python': free(): invalid size: 0x0000000000de4e80 ***
Aborted (core dumped).

I deleted each line one by one and found the problem line being:
from caffe2.python import core, workspace, models

If I remove this, it will import without issue.

Now, if I import this via the python IDE it works.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks